# MouseMove Event not behaving as expected

Tags: wpf, vb.net, mousemove

I am writing my first code to handle a Drag and Drop Event in WPF / VB.Net.

To act as a learning exercise, I am trying to initiate a DoDragDrop when the left button is pressed over a Button Control. I thought this would be achieved as follows:

```
Private Sub ButtonYield_MouseMove(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles ButtonYield.MouseMove

    If e.LeftButton = MouseButtonState.Pressed Then
        'Drag Drop Code Here
        MsgBox("Event Called")
    End If

End Sub
```

In practice, though, this event is only called if the left button is pressed *prior* to the mouse moving over the Button Control.

Is there something fundamental that I am missing here?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is behaving as expected, your code is checking for the mouse moving when the left button is clicked. You need to keep track of when the mouse if clicked on your button and only then do the drag drop if the mouse moves. Something along these lines (untested):

```
Private _mouseDownOverButton As Boolean = False

Private Sub ButtonYield_MouseLeave(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles ButtonYield.MouseLeave
    _mouseDownOverButton = False
End Sub

Private Sub ButtonYield_MouseLeftButtonDown(sender As Object, e As MouseButtonEventArgs) Handles ButtonYield.MouseLeftButtonDown
    _mouseDownOverButton = True
End Sub

Private Sub ButtonYield_MouseLeftButtonUp(sender As Object, e As MouseButtonEventArgs) Handles ButtonYield.MouseLeftButtonUp
    _mouseDownOverButton = False
End Sub

Private Sub ButtonYield_MouseMove(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles ButtonYield.MouseMove
    If _mouseDownOverButton Then
        'drag drop code here
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Perfect - that's filled a gap in my knowledge